# Is there an element selector by name?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `button` with `name` - `btn01`. Is there any type of selector or other technique to `select`/`get` this element if I have its name in variable. For example:

```
var name = "btn01";
var buttton = GetButtonByName(name);
```

You can do this easily in `Javascript/jQuery` and I need such technique here, too.

Also, all elements are in grid and I can easily get it by name.

Comment: Is this in a WPF application, or server-side web?

Comment: It is a `Black App (Windows Phone) Visual C#` project.

Comment: in code behind just use `btn01` as a variable name, it should be already defined

Comment: @thumbmunkeys The point is it should be dynamic - I am building the name and then I need to select the particular element and do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`FindName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method on `FrameworkElement` - invoke that method on the parent element, and I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Jean pointed out, you can use FindName method

```
public T GetElementByName<T>(string elementName)
         {
                return (T) this.FindName(elementName); 
         }
```